# Problema ao consumir webservice do DataSUS em PHP

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Segue o código:

```
            <?php   
            $client = new SoapClient('https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/v5r0?wsdl');
                                $function = "Pesquisar";
                                $arguments = array("Pesquisar" => 
                                                array(
                                                    "CNESUsuario" => array("CNES" =>"6963447", "Usuario"=>"LEONARDO", "Senha"=>"?"),
                                                    "FiltroPesquisa" => array("CPF"=> array("numeroCPF"=>"66105234368"), "tipoPesquisa"=>"IDENTICA"),
                                                    "higienizar" => "0"
                                                )
                                            );
                                $result = $client->__soapCall($function,$arguments);
                                print($result); 

            ?>
```

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

```
                Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Receiver ] nested fault: XML parse failed: libxml error: : level: 3, code: 5, file: none, line: 1, str1: "", str2: "", str3: "", int1: 0, int2: 37, message: Extra content at the end of the document in *...\cadsus.php:12 Stack trace: #0 *...\cadsus.php(12): SoapClient->__soapCall('Pesquisar', Array) #1 {main} thrown in *...\cadsus.php on line 12
```

Alguma solução?

Comment: "*message: Extra content at the end of the document*", qual foi o XML gerado?

Comment: Então, não consigo fazer o parse, mesmo usando um parse_str ele retorna um erro. Usando um exemplo no SoapUI ele retorna certinho. Parece que não consigo printar o XML na página.

Comment: Algum avanço nessa integração com o webservice do cadsus? Também consegui realizar todos os teste no SOAPUI, tanto para Homologação e produção, porém Não consigo avançar no PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive Esse erro pois faltava o header com a autenticação, pra resolver inclui manualmente com soapVar.
segue codigo exemplo que funciona pra mim.

```html
<?php
try {
    $wsdlUrl = 'https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/v5r0?wsdl';
    $wsUser = 'CADSUS.CNS.PDQ.PUBLICO';
    $passWs = 'kUXNmiiii#RDdlOELdoe00966';
    $soapClientOptions = array(
 'trace' => 1,
 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
    $xmlheader = '
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F6C95C679D248B6E3F143032021465917">
        <wsse:Username>' . $wsUser . '</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">' . $passWs . '</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
';
    $header = new SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'Security', new \SoapVar($xmlheader, XSD_ANYXML), false);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $requestPesquisar = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario->CNES = '6963447';
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario->Usuario = 'LEONARDO';
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario->Senha = '?';
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->nomeCompleto = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->nomeCompleto->Nome = 'SERGIO ARAUJO CORREIA LIMA';
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->tipoPesquisa = 'IDENTICA';
    $requestPesquisar->higienizar = '0';
    $result = $client->pesquisar($requestPesquisar);
    if ($result) {
 echo '<pre>', print_r($result), '</pre>';
    } else {
 echo '<h2>Request:</h2>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($client->__getLastRequest()), '</pre>';
 echo '<h2>Header:</h2>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($client->__getLastRequestHeaders()), '</pre>';
 echo '<h2>Response:</h2>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($client->__getLastResponse()), '</pre>';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r($e), '<pre>';
}
?>
```

agora estou com outro problema esse webservice não retorna dados completos do paciente, ex: não retorna o endereço, municipio de residencia etc...

na versão PDQ/PIX é mais completo mas não consegui executar com PHP.

Espero que ajude.

abraço!

Comment: Olá André! Muito obrigado pelo seu retorno! Esse problema que você está enfrentando é devido às credenciais fornecidas para teste. Para você conseguir retornar todos os dados completos, deverá fazer os processos para homologação a fim de obter as credenciais completas de acesso ao webservice.

Comment: Olá Mosquito! eu utilizei as credenciais de um município cliente meu, que ja utilizou outro sistema integrado ao barramento e tive a decepção de não retornar os dados completos, então utilizei o exemplo da integração PIX/PDQ no soapUi e retornou os dados completos. Mas não tenho idéia de como usar esse PIX/PDQ no PHP

Answer (score 1):

Segue solução para consumir esse webservice em php.

```
class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader {

 private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

 function __construct($user, $pass, $ns = null) {
     if ($ns) {
         $this->wss_ns = $ns;
     }
     $auth = new stdClass();
     $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns); 
     $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);

     $username_token = new stdClass();
     $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns); 

     $security_sv = new SoapVar(
         new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),
         SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);
     parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
 }
}
```

```
function consulta_CNS_Base_Nacional($cns){

     $UserName = "<<usuário>>";
     $Password = '<<senha>>';

     $wsse_header = new WsseAuthHeader($UserName, $Password );

     $opts = array( 
         'ssl' => array(
             'verify_peer' => false,
             'verify_peer_name' => false,
             'allow_self_signed' => true
         )
     ); 
     $context = stream_context_create($opts); 

     $options = array( 
                 'trace'           => 1, 
                 'stream_context' => $context
                  );
     try
     {
     $client = new SoapClient('https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/v5r0?wsdl', $options); 

         $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));

         $dataSus = new stdClass;        
         $dataSus = new stdClass;
         $dataSus->CNESUsuario = new stdClass;
         $dataSus->CNESUsuario->CNES = "6963447";
         $dataSus->CNESUsuario->Usuario = "LEONARDO";

         $dataSus->CNS = new stdClass;
         $dataSus->CNS->numeroCNS = $cns;

         $method = 'consultar';

         $result = $client->__soapCall($method, array($dataSus));

         /*
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->NomeCompleto->Nome;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Mae->Nome;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Pai->Nome;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Sexo->codigoSexo;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->dataNascimento;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->RacaCor->codigoRacaCor;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->Municipio->codigoMunicipio;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->EtniaIndigena->codigoEtniaIndigena;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->TipoSanguineo;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->DadosNacionalidade->PaisNascimento->codigoPais;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->MunicipioNascimento->codigoMunicipio;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->MunicipioNascimento->UF->codigoUF;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->MunicipioNascimento->UF->siglaUF;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Documentos->Identidade->numeroIdentidade;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->TipoLogradouro->codigoTipoLogradouro;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->TipoLogradouro->descricaoTipoLogradouro;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->nomeLogradouro;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->numero;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->complemento;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->Bairro->descricaoBairro;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->CEP->numeroCEP;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->Municipio->codigoMunicipio;
             echo '</br>';    
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->Municipio->UF->codigoUF;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Enderecos->Endereco->Municipio->UF->siglaUF;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Telefones->Telefone->DDD;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Telefones->Telefone->numeroTelefone;
             echo '</br>';
             echo $result->UsuarioSUS->Emails->Email[0]->descricaoEmail;
             echo '</br>';

             print_r($result);
             */
         }
         catch(Exception $e) 
         { 
             echo $e->getMessage(); 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

infelizmente não tenho privilégios para comentar, tentei algumas coisas aqui pra tentar te ajudar, mas me parece que o problema está no xml de respotsa do webservice. Eu reescrevi o código um pouco diferente do seu, e sempre tive o mesmo resultado.

A biblioteca do Xml está reclamando que o documento xml da respota tem mais de uma raiz e o XMl semanticamente falando só pode ter uma raiz.

Ruim

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<status>success</status>
<format>xml</format>
```

Bom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <status>success</status>
  <format>xml</format>
</response>
```

O xml de resposta deveria ser o seguinte no PHP

```
<soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <env:Value xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">env:Sender</env:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="pt-BR">Uma ou mais regras negociais foram violadas, verifique a lista de erros.</soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
         <soap:Detail>
            <msf:MSFalha xmlns:msf="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/falha/v5r0/msfalha">
               <msf:Mensagem xmlns:men="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/falha/v5r0/mensagem">
                  <men:codigo>OSB_SEM_AUTENTICACAO</men:codigo>
                  <men:descricao>As credenciais informadas não são válidas</men:descricao>
               </msf:Mensagem>
            </msf:MSFalha>
         </soap:Detail>
      </soap:Fault>
```

Esse xml tem code, reason, Detail ao que tudo indica como raiz

se você pegar esse xml, que o SOAPUI apresenta como respota  e colocar em um validador de XMl, vai notar que ele está errado, você pode usar esse link, do [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) para isso, eu não sou especialista em XML, isto é apenas resultado de uma pesquisa e de debug

Abaixo o códido que escrevi caso tenha curiosidade

```
<?php

//318707

$pesquisar = new stdClass();
$pesquisar->CNESUsuario = new stdClass();
$pesquisar->CNESUsuario->CNES = "6963447";
$pesquisar->CNESUsuario->Usuario = "LEONARDO";
$pesquisar->CNESUsuario->Senha = "";
$pesquisar->FiltroPesquisa = new stdClass();
$pesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->CPF = new stdClass();
$pesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->CPF->numeroCPF = "66105234368";
$pesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->tipoPesquisa = "IDENTICA";
$pesquisar->higienizar = false;


$ver = "v5r0";

$url = "https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/$ver?wsdl";

// Opções de configurações do cliente WSDL
$options = [
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, // SOAP_1_2
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
];

$soap = new SoapClient($url, $options);

$result  = $soap->Pesquisar($pesquisar);
print $result;
```

Dei uma olhada na documentaçãom desse webservice e notei que existe um video a respeito de como implementar essa solução em java e o Soapui é feito em java,não sei que mágica o java faz pra conseguir entender essa respota.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento Jeferson! Eu cheguei a ler todo o manual e vi esses exemplos em Java. De qualquer maneira vou continuar tentando aqui haha :D Qualquer avanço vou postar aqui para quem tiver o mesmo problema.